# Crystal Reports group wise suppress field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

```
  Name         Rupees          Company
Group 1st

   A            50             A
   B            70             B
   C            45             C  

Group 2nd
  D             150            D
  E             100            E
  G             60             F
```

and I want the result

```
Name         Rupees          Company
Group 1st

   A            50             
   B            70             B
   C            45               

Group 2nd
  D             150            D
  E             100            
  G             60
```

i want to suppress the Company filed on Maximum Rupees Filed and also Group wise.

Comment: If you want to suppress Company Field (The one that is printing A, D) then why are you displaying it. If it is suppressed then nothing will be displayed under Company...

Comment: @Sivaraman i want to suppress the Company Filed using Formula.And i want to display only company which have maximum rupees in current Group.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can write a supress condition of Company column.

Code looks something like this.

```
if(maximum(filed))=Group1 (Ruppes)
Then false
Else True
```

By this if the maximum of the required filed matches with the max of the group1 then the company part will display..rest of others will get supressed.

This should work
Let me know if you still face any issue.